# Open android Front camera and Back camera at the same time

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to receive data from front camera and back at the same time on Android 2.3.3. 
Can I use two cameras at the same time and receive data by onPreviewFrame ?

Or another way to get data from two cameras at the same time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I read in API 2.3 for multiple cameras selection, only one camera at the same time can be open. So officialy not, but there can be some kind of hack maybe.