# Using both cameras on android: "Fail to connect to camera service"

Tags: android, video, camera

I'm having troubles in accessing both (front and rear cameras at the same time). 
When turn on one camera it works. 
When i turn off first and turn on second it works.
It gives following exception when i'm trying to turn on second camera while the first one is still showing the image.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(32325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(32325): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
E/AndroidRuntime(32325):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32325):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:265)
E/AndroidRuntime(32325):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(32325):    at com.example.videostreamer.MainActivity$CameraHandler.start(MainActivity.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime(32325):    at com.example.videostreamer.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
E/AndroidRuntime(32325):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
E/AndroidRuntime(32325):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
```

In the documentaion i found a phrase that says:

> public static Camera open (int cameraId)
>
> Since: API Level 9
>   Creates a new Camera object to access a particular hardware camera.
>   You must call release() when you are done using the camera, otherwise it will remain 
>   locked and be unavailable to other applications.
>   **Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time for a particular
>   hardware camera.**

.. but i'm having only one Camera object for one hardware camera and I wanted to create second object for second device.

1. Does anybody know if this is possible (I'm using Android 2.3.3)?
2. The place: android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method) can suggest that probably it is hardware/driver limitation - I'm using HTC Sensation.

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate, but there are much more popular discussions of the related topic: *[Using both front and back cameras simultaneously android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11419940/192373)*

Comment: Multicamera support has been added in Android10. They included the instructions in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u38wOv2a_dA

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676859/open-android-front-camera-and-back-camera-at-the-same-time) question basically says it cannot be done, but there may be some hack. [This](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/34ba69f6650b6b97) lack of response from google groups tells me most likely not. [Here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2bba92c6305f157b/ee5f4aeed2bfc26a?show_docid=ee5f4aeed2bfc26a) is another no-response post on google groups. [Here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/161074) is another post discussing the use of two cameras at the same time.

So my initial answer is no, it is not possible. BUT there may be some workaround, you just may have to find it yourself because it isn't discovered yet :).

EDIT 11/21/11: Unfortunately I found even further proof that it cannot be done, official from Sprint/HTC [here](http://developer.sprint.com/show_thread.do?forumId=528&threadid=26999&messageId=78914). I realize you are using a Sensation, and this is an EVO 4g, but I'm sure it still applies.

Answer (score 3):

Both cameras can be launched together as long as the hardware supports it. First you need to find the specific SoC used by your phone. You can find this by using the command

```
$ adb shell getprop
```

Chech the field [ro.board.platform], For Nexus 6 it returns

```
[ro.board.platform]: [msm8084]
```

Now you would need to check if this chipset has dual-ISP capability in hardware. For Qualcomm snapdragon chipsets you can find it [here](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Snapdragon). For Samsung Exynos you can find it [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/samsungsemiconductor/pdfs/Samsung_Exynos_Final_HR.pdf). Now if your device supports dual camera and has latest OS installed in it, then you can use this application [(ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382322/is-it-possible-to-use-front-and-back-camera-at-same-time-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top) developed by [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3094508/user3094508) to verify if the dual camera works. It should probably work, it does work on my Nexus 6.
Video: http://youtu.be/lt8N1Lpa9Zw

Thanks, Jai

Comment: Unfortunately, Samsung S4 and S5 do not expose public API to open dual camera, as discussed in *[How to capture both front and back cameras in Galaxy S4 simultaneously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061045/how-to-capture-both-front-and-back-cameras-in-galaxy-s4-simultaneously)*. Also, confirmed on [**Samsung Developers** forum](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/a/201/247737).

Answer (score -1):

I also wanted to do the same, but can't achieve it, its limitation of android os.

You HAVE TO RELEASE the connected camera object to be accessed by another.

The same problem is faced while accessing AudioRecord class, you just can't make an object of it until you release the first one.

Comment: This is not a limitation of OS; the API does not prohibit opening two instances of Camera simultaneously. It's the implementations that don't allow us to keep two cameras open. Unfortunately, some devices do not expose this functionality to 3rd parties even though they are fully capable (e.g. Samsung S4 and S5 phones). On the other hand, Snapdragon-801 based phones often work, see more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28811277/192373).