# How to create two camera preview in one Activity?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

Anybody know how to create two camera preview in one Activity? One preview SurfaceView for back camera,and the other for front camera.

Comment: Display what have u attempt?

Comment: I want to record video both from front and back camera. It seem that I can only access one camera at once.Hope that function will be added into new Android Framework.

Answer (score 2):

Most Android devices do not let you access both cameras at once. In fact, the S4 is the only production device that I am aware of that does this.

You can only show one camera at a time due to this.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17061045/1069068) is another thread on the S4's cameras.