# Accessing Front and Back Camera in Android at the same time

Tags: android

I want to access the front and back camera at the same time. Is this possible? From what I tested, this could not be done. It crashes if an application is already accessing the back camera and another app is trying to access the front camera.

I found few previous posting here but there is no answer to this:

[Can we access at a time Camera in multiple application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835894/can-we-access-at-a-time-camera-in-multiple-application)

[Open android Front camera and Back camera at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676859/open-android-front-camera-and-back-camera-at-the-same-time)

But what I don't understand is why is there such a limitation?

Isn't front and back cameras are two different pieces of hardware?

Or can this be done and am I wrong?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: This is an old good question, and it received a well-articulated answer timely. It is worth linking to some new developments in this area, e.g. [Using both front and back cameras simultaneously android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28811277/192373) *(incidentally, this question was asked only month later, but got much more publicity)*. TL;NR: some devices circa 2015 let you access front and back camera at the same time,  within the same old API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://tinyurl.com/bp4fec5):

> Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time.

The camera module is switched to either the front or back-facing camera. There is no design to launch both of them at the same time. HTC has confirmed this [**here**](http://developer.sprint.com/show_thread.do?forumId=528&threadid=26999&messageId=78914). Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I assume that this is a limitation by Android OS itself? How about other brands other than HTC? Should be the same right?

Comment: Probably. There are a bunch of threads on the internet that ask your same question, and I haven't come across anyone who has successfully achieved this. If it can't be done using the public API, I doubt there is a safe means of hacking your way around it either.

Comment: Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time for a particular hardware camera.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is wrong.

You CAN have both at the same time.  This is the actual line from that linked documentation:

Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time **for a particular hardware camera.**