# Dual Camera simultaneous recording for both front and rear cameras

Tags: android, android-camera

We ask if the following requirement can be done on Android.

Need to have dual simultaneous Camera recording for both front and rear cameras

So if i can't record direct it's possible to take 50 frames per second for each camera ?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11419940/3001761

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take photo with front and rear camera simultaneously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770722/how-to-take-photo-with-front-and-rear-camera-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

> if i can't record direct it's possible to take 50 frames per second for each camera ?

The short, but final answer is **No**.

The linked discussions describe niche cases where some kind of simultaneous access to dual camera is enabled.