# Android - Utilise both front and back cameras in app

Tags: android

I have searched quite a bit about whether or not it is possible to utilise both front and back cameras simultaneously in app. I found threads from several years ago saying it is possible on certain devices and on all Samsung phones after something like the S4. However that feature is locked to Samsung developed applications only.  I then looked into whether or not it is possible to switch rapidly between the two cameras to achieve the same goal but apparently that would be extremely taxing on the hardware. I was wondering if anyone has some information about this in 2017 and if developing an application that is able to use both front and back cameras simultaneously is viable?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way late but here are two post I made on this to help anyone who runs into this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28811277/1138878

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43445052/1138878

Short answer: it's possible but depends on hardware/chipset (Snapdragon 801 and higher level hardware).

What it boils down to is that you need a Camera object for each camera which feeds a SurfaceView for each camera. Also make sure to check, in code, the capabilities (resolution and image format) and use one of the supported formats/sizes.