# Front and Back camera on the same screen app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

Well, I was just browsing around toogit and some dude wanted an app which has the functionality of "streaming" both front and back cameras of an android phone to a cloud at the same time on a single screen. Well, I ignored the streaming part, but I looked up the both cameras on the same screen part. Found a project which did exactly that minus any record/click buttons. However, when I ran it on a couple of phones..it worked on "oreo" but not on "pie". This cannot go to playstore because the targeted SDK version needs to be low..It is 17 for me. Has this function been blocked at the OEM level by some companies or is it an issue with the android version. Thanks.

Comment: Neither... it is phone-dependent. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419940/using-both-front-and-back-cameras-simultaneously-android).

Comment: @greeble31 So, that is OEM, why do you say neither?

Comment: Based on the phrasing of your question, it sounded to me like you thought the OEMs might have made a change Oreo vs. Pie. At any rate, apologies for the confusion, but you have your answer.

Comment: @greeble31 Oh! Sorry about that..I am not at all familiar with how OEM's choice with oreo or pie goes. That wasn't my intention. Curious though, what will go wrong if they allow this?

Comment: I wouldn't think of it as "blocking". As some of the other discussions on this site mention, it is probably more to do with hardware limitations; e.g., the capacity of their camera bus, etc. Not a lot of consumers are clamoring for this feature; just engineers :)

Comment: @greeble31 yea..that...I can relate to.. Just Engineers, just to show off. We are just ..NOT in a position to think like them(OEMs and Android devs). Anyways..the question is answered, I suppose.