# Access multiple cameras at the same time in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a Flutter app which uses the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/example) package to display the user's front camera.

This is done by using a `CameraController`, for example:

```
final List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();
var frontCamera = cameras[0];

final CameraController cameraController = CameraController(
      frontCamera,
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      enableAudio: enableAudio,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
    );

// Return a live feed of the user's camera
return CameraPreview(cameraController);
```

The above is working correctly. However when I use `cameras[1]` to display an image of the back camera at the same time, the back camera image is blank:

```
final List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();
var frontCamera = cameras[0];
var backCamera = cameras[1];

final CameraController frontCameraController = CameraController(
      frontCamera,
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      enableAudio: enableAudio,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
    );

final CameraController backCameraController = CameraController(
      backCamera,
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      enableAudio: enableAudio,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
    );


return Column(
    children: [
        // Front camera is shown correctly
        CameraPreview(frontCameraController),

        // Back camera image is blank
        CameraPreview(backCameraController),
    ],
);
```

How do I show the image from two cameras at the same time with Flutter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Front and Back Camera in Android at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679261/accessing-front-and-back-camera-in-android-at-the-same-time)

Comment: No, as it does not appear to be related to Flutter

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that the flutter camera package isn't designed to handle multiple cameras at once. If you need that functionality I think you might have to find a different package or write one yourself/adapt from the flutter plugin...